# Adding UIViewController's .view to UITableViewCell makes its button to not receive touches

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, subview

I have a tableview that has 3 rows (1st ads, 2nd content, 3rd content description)

Inside my tableViewCell for the content:

```
-(void)setupCell{ 

MyViewController* vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.contentView addSubview:vc.view];
}
```

The orange view is MyViewController that doesn't recieve touches
[image]

And on MyViewController's nib I added a button with an IBAction that prints a string to check if it's working but it never gets called when I tried tapping it.

I don't know what is causing this problem, been stuck with it for a few hours.

Comment: can you share your codes includes your views ?

Comment: @zeytin I added a few additional information